# Cannot read property of undefined. How to define?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-fullstack

I am trying to run a custom PUT in Angularjs, however I cannot for the life of me get it to work. I need both UserResource and user to be defined but only the parameter in the first position of the update function gets defined. What can I do to define both user and UserResource?

```
(function () {

class AdminController {
  constructor(User, Auth) {
    this.users = User.query();
    this.Auth = Auth;
  }

//here user is defined and I can run the delete function
  delete(user) {
    user.$remove();
    this.users.splice(this.users.indexOf(user), 1);
  }

// and if I put user into the first position it is defined but UserResource isn't 
// as written here it isn't defined either. 
  update(UserResource, user) {
    var $id = user._id;
    UserResource.update({ id:$id }, user);
  }
}

angular.module('wcsdesktopApp.admin')
  .controller('AdminController', AdminController);
})();
```

**EDIT to add more information**

I call the update function like this:

```
  <table>
    <tr>
      <a ng-click="admin.update(user)" class="update"><span class="fa fa-refresh fa-2x"></span></a>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <a ng-click="admin.delete(user)" class="trash"><span class="fa fa-trash fa-2x"></span></a>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

I included the delete function for reference since that is working.

UserResource is an AngularJS [$resource](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource) custom put request.

```
(function() {

function UserResource($resource) {
  return $resource('/api/users/:id/:controller', {
    id: '@_id'
  }, {
    changePassword: {
      method: 'PUT',
      params: {
        controller: 'password'
      }
    },
    update: {
      method: 'PUT'
    },
    get: {
      method: 'GET',
      params: {
        id: 'me'
      }
    }
  });
}

angular.module('wcsdesktopApp.auth')
  .factory('User', UserResource);

})();
```

Comment: How are you calling `update`? Is `UserResource` supposed to be a service of some kind?

Comment: I updated the question with more information. Let me know if that helps

Comment: You have to inject your service into your controller. That's why that part isn't working. I can give you a full answer in a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure that you are injecting your `UserResource` service into your controller. One of the many ways would be like the below:

```
angular.module('wcsdesktopApp.admin').controller('AdminController', AdminController);
AdminController.$inject = [ 'User'];
function AdminController(User) {}
```

Doing that would then change your `update` signature in your controller to the following:

```
update(user) {
    User.update(); // Do whatever update.
}
```

Comment: I implemented the code you suggested. I get back 

`ReferenceError: UserResource is not defined`

Comment: I missed the fact you named the service `User` but the function `UserResource`. I've updated the answer to reflect that but you might want to consider naming them the same to make clear what you are calling.

Comment: Sorry to be a hassle but, I followed your recommendations in the updated answer and standardized the names to `User` and I am still getting the same error.

Comment: Looking it back over it appears that you put the controller and service in different modules (one in admin and one in auth). Do one of the modules inject the other?

Comment: The  User is defined when I change `update` to `$update` like this:
`update(user) {
    User.$update(); // Do whatever update.
}`

however, now I seem to be getting at 500 error from my Mongodb. So your answer did help me fix my problem.